# GWT 2.3 dev mode - Hosted mode JSP compilation appears to not use java 1.5 compatibility

Tags: java, gwt

> Unable to compile class for JSP
>
> Generated servlet error:  @DefaultMessage("Last Updated:
>   {0,date,medium}  {0,time, HH:mm:ss (z)}")     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Syntax
>   error, annotations are only available if source level is 1.5

I've got such errors for all 1.5+ features like enums, annotations etc. during trying to open my gwt module in web browser in dev mode. Compilation process goes well. And my modules work in production/deployment mode. The error appears all over the project only when I open open my module in dev mode.

Compiler compliance level in eclipse is set to 1.6.

This error is the same as [Issue 3557](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=3557) BUT this is old issue for GWT 1.5-1.6 and I'm using GWT 2.3. Also I'm only one GWt developer in my project so I cannot compare my settings/copy eclipse project from someone's workspace.

My waring/errors perspective output is clean, no connected messages with this problem. I've also tried to recheckout from repository and recreate my project in eclipse - but the situation is the same.

Also I've got another [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9454641/eclipse-3-6-tomcat-does-not-put-jars-from-deployment-assembly-to-its-deployment) which I think may be connected with this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you suggested yourself this is a very old GWT issue with the embedded development server.

To get around this

- you could use your own server (see -noserver option)
- use one of the suggested workarounds in the issue(I used to write my own java class for brining up jetty with java 1.6 as the default compiler