# Eclipse 3.6 Tomcat does not put jars from deployment assembly to it's deployment tmp dir

Tags: java, tomcat

The are two "kinds" of jars in my project. One - jars made from projects which ,my project is depend from (e.g. my-second-project.jar), another - jars which are third-party libraries (e.g. hibernate.jar). The second kind of jars DOES NOT appear in  deployment tmp dir while the first DOES.

I'm using eclipse 3.6, my project is dynamic web project, my tomcat version is 6.0.28. I've tried to recteate it - it doesn't help. I've also got similar web-project which works well.

I've made temporary work-around - I've put my jars directly to classpath. But this is just work-arond, but not the problem reason.

My waring/errors perspective output is clean, no connected messages whith this problem. Also I've got another "interesting" problem which might be connected whith this one. It's described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9454465/gwt-2-3-dev-mode-hosted-mode-jsp-compilation-appears-to-not-use-java-1-5-compa)

Any help would be appreciated cause I've tried everything I can and I realy don't know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have two projects, one depending on the other? And you don't get the jars from the project that the other project depends on? If so, make sure the jar files are exported from the first project: right click on the project, Build Path -> Configure Build Path... and then go to the "Order and Export" tab and tick the jar files you want to export.

Comment: No, I don't get jars from the current project. E.g. I've got folder "libs" in my project, I've added jars from this folder to Build Path and Deployment Assembly. My project compiles well, but jars don't move to Tomcat's tmp deployment folder when I publish them. No warnings, errors. Another similar project works well.